# Regex working with PHP but not with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, css, regex

I've a **regex string** that get the value from a **CSS code** like that

```
body {
  background: #000;
}
/* drapeDecalage: 10px */
```

and I want to parse the **commented** `drapeDecalage` value. 
For that I'm using **regex**, and I've made an expression like that:

```
(?<=\/\* drapeDecalage: )(.*?)(?=px \*\/)
```

wich is perfectly working in **PHP**, but not in **Javascript**, I've got this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=\/\* drapeDecalage: )(.*?)(?=px \*\/)/: Invalid group
```

with this **code**:

```
var re = /(?<=\/\* drapeDecalage: )(.*?)(?=px \*\/)/; 
var str = '/* drapeDecalage: 10px */';

console.log(re.exec(str));
```

Demo at **Regex101** with `PHP PCRE` https://regex101.com/r/nL2yX9/2

Javascript code demo at `JSFiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/wd574aw3/

**What's wrong?** *How to fix that?* 

Thanks

Comment: There is no lookbehind in Javascript regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a fact that current JavaScript regex engine does not support a lookbehind (no idea if/when it will be supported at all).

Thus, you need to remove the lookbehind (the `?<=` part) from your PHP pattern and just match that subpattern, and get the value you need from the first capturing group (captured with `(.*?)`):

```
/\/\* drapeDecalage: (.*?)(?=px \*\/)/
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bS0bY8/1)

```js
var re = /\/\* drapeDecalage: (.*?)(?=px \*\/)/; 
var str = 'body {\n  background: #000;\n}\n/* drapeDecalage: 10px */';
if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
   document.body.innerHTML = m[1]; // m[1] contains the drapeDecalage value
}
```

Note that instead of literal spaces, you can use `\s*` to match zero or more whitespace.

Also, if you know there are only digits before `px */`, you can use `(\d+)` instead of `(.*?)` (lazy dot matching pattern is not the best construct to use when the type of data is known).

So, an alternative regex would look like:

```
/\/\*\s*drapeDecalage:\s*(\d+)(?=px\s*\*\/)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bS0bY8/2)

Comment: Working, thanks. Just waiting delay to valid your answer

Comment: In most cases, you do not need a lookbehind. This is one of them. Even in PHP, I'd advise to use capturing groups to  retrieve such contextual values - regexps without lookbehinds at the pattern start usually perform better.